# Как правильно строить макеты экранов?

Tags: java, android, gui

Как правильно строить макеты экранов (или писать приложения) для разных разрешениев экранов, просто получается так что приложение на разных экранах выглядит по разному.

Comment: Андроид предлагает различные типы лейаутов. Вы можете их комбинировать для наилучшего отопбражения. Лейауты могут быть вложенными. Можете пройти курс на udacity, там про это разказывают. Я б нарисовал пример,но у меня сейчас моб инет(
Если все еще будет интересно -- пишите в Лс в понедельник,с удовольствием помогу. Плюс,покажите конкретно ваш пример)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, чтобы интерфейс приложения выглядел одинаково на различных устройствах, необходимо использовать относительные (а не абсолютные) размер и позиционирование элементов интерфейса.

В частности вместо единицы измерения `px` нужно использовать единицу измерения `dp` (**density-independent** pixels).

Также следует использовать графические элементы различных разрешений для экранов с различными PPI.

Все вышесказанное является только лишь **необходимым**, но **не достаточным**. Иными словами – это все *как минимум*.

Comment: если я буду использовать `dp`, то кнопки и все остальное не будут съезжать со своих мест?

Comment: Все эти условия скорее необходимые, чем достаточные. Если Вы будете использовать `px` – то элементы гарантировано будут по-разному отображаться на устройствах с различными разрешениями. А вообще, лучше всего позиционировать элементы друг *относительно* друга, а не задавать им какие-либо *смещения* в каких бы то ни было единицах измерения.

Comment: Понял вас, спасибо

Comment: В любом случае, лучше всего проверять как выглядит интерфейс приложения на устройствах с различными характеристиками. Можете на эмуляторах посмотреть.

Comment: Ок, буду тестить, спасибо)